# How to deal with my fear of large audiences?

Tags: teaching, presentation

I am having problems facing audiences. During my primary and secondary school period I had inferiority complexes due to my size. Therefore I always skipped and ran from debates, but now I graduated with a good grade from university. I am a teacher now and still have this phobia of facing crowds. No matter how I prepare, whenever I stand in front of the crowd, my voice will be shaking. I really need your advice because I tried every method, but they are not working and it's depressing.

Comment: Which methods _have_ you tried? Have you tried using the service of a professional trainer or psychologist?

Comment: This might be something more appropriate to discuss with a psychologist than on a StackExchange like SE.Academia.  A good response would be highly specific to you, personally, and likely be arrived at after a long dialog.

Comment: Took me a while - at first I didn’t really look at the students : just focused on a point at the back of the room, lots of practise helps and, while they don’t know, the good students do too - asking polite well thought out questions, contributing ...

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't tried one of the [beta blockers prescribed for performance anxiety/stage fright](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2008/08/in-defense-of-the-beta-blocker/306961/), they're worth looking into.

For me, using [propranolol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propranolol) before presentations has been much more helpful than I ever expected, and has even had carry over effects. (Basically I suck at talking to most people most of the time, but now I suck less!) Just having the experience of speaking without the physical effects of anxiety turned out to be powerful. Something about breaking the feedback loop, I guess -

The fact that you mention your voice shaking, especially, makes me think beta blockers might help you.